# UILabel int array concatenation

Tags: arrays, cocoa, uilabel, concatenation

Ok I want to read an array of int's concatenated into a UILabel Here's the code I have. I cannot figure out how to concat them as I am building a number filter system and want to display remaining numbers in a UILabel.

```
-(IBAction)print {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        if(myArray[i] != 0){
          printScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i,",myArray[i]];
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
-(IBAction)print {
    NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if(myArray[i] != 0) {
            [text appendFormat:@"%d,", myArray[i]];
        }
    }
    printScreen.text = text;
}
```

Comment: @JacobHolman: Maybe it got cut off in your label, but the output of this is “[snip],98,99,100,”.